# How to select other range sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm making group of sliders using HTML's `input` range object. When one slider is moved, the others should move the same amount to the opposite direction.

I can move the "slider_02" with `document.querySelector("#slider_02").value` but I need to move all the other sliders.

Can I use for example "not" and what should I put then for "X" in `X:not(#slider_01)`?

**My problem is how to select the other sliders.**

Answer (score 1):

> My problem is how to select the other sliders.

You could use `document.querySelectorAll('slider:not')` to get all sliders and `:not` selector like `slider:not('#slider_01')` to get all sliders except the one with `id="slider_01"`:

```
var sliders = document.querySelectorAll("slider:not('#slider_01')")
```

And you should loop through all the slider and change the value of every one :

```
var i;

for (i = 0; i < sliders.length; ++i) {
    sliders[i].value = X;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is tagged with jQuery you could use [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) function.

Here is an example:

```js
jQuery('.slider').on('input change', function() {
  _this = jQuery(this);

   // Perform any action you want
    var totalValue = parseFloat(_this.attr('max'));
   
   var leftValue = totalValue - jQuery(this).val();
   
  jQuery(this).siblings().each(function(i, e) {
   console.log(leftValue);
      jQuery(e).val(leftValue);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" name="points" min="0" max="10" class='slider'><br>
<input type="range" name="points" min="0" max="10" class='slider'><br>
<input type="range" name="points" min="0" max="10" class='slider'><br>
<input type="range" name="points" min="0" max="10" class='slider'><br>
```